# Can we enable only BLE on Intel Edison and disable BT so that Edison remains only in BLE mode?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, intel-edison

I am trying to connect my Android phone to Intel Edison via BLE.
I want to make sure BT is turned off and BLE is on.

Answer (score 0):

Since both modes, classic BR/EDR and LE, are usually controlled by the same microcontroller, this wont work.

I did not find any way to disable BR/EDR functionality on the software side.

Comment: Thanks Dominik, Do you know any way to start Gatt server on Intel Edison and connect it to android phone over BLE?

Comment: Sorry, i dont own such board, maybe the following howto gives hints on how to do it https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/connecting-to-intel-edison-from-android-with-bluetooth-le-ble